# Why does changing contentsize value of scrollView doesnot effect the result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

while using scrollview i have assigned `contentSize (0,508)`

if i change it to `(-77,508)` or `(150,508)` shows same result.

which result in myView top side doesnot comes down (how ever if i change the value of myView to `Y = 250`) it runs good.
But it doesnot look good in storyboard as myView bottom side goes way down the builder.

Any ideas, what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentSize` property is responsible for (literally) the size of your content. Setting it to `(150, 508)` says "I want my content to be 150pt wide and 508pt tall". It defines how far side-to-side or top-to-bottom your content *can* scroll. It does not say anything about its actual position. If you want to change the position of the view inside the scroll view, either change the subview's frame or take a look at `contentOffset` property of the scroll view

Comment: Sounds like a very clear explanation :) Hence up vote :)

Comment: thanks mate, i always thought it is starting Y position.

Comment: so if i only want it to scroll vertically i would say `ContentSize(0,508)`

Comment: if you only want to scroll vertically, you need your `contentSize` to be as wide as the `scrollView` itself. e.g `contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width` and as tall to accommodate your actual content

Comment: @SandeepBhandari but i still have same issue, my view goes up side and below half screen looks empty, Can any one explain how do i set the position of view inside my scroll view